# On the regularized gamma function (analysis problem)

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

I have a quick question on the regularized gamma function, defined as

$Q (a,z)=\frac{\Gamma(a,z)}{\Gamma(a)} \,. [1]$

What is the value of $Q (a,z)$ in the asymptotic limits $a \rightarrow \infty$ and $z \rightarrow \infty$ ?

[1] see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html

Comment: The limit and asymptotic as $a \to +\infty $ is not hard, what did you try ?

Comment: I am not familiar with asymptotic calculus. But what I tried as a first guest is to increase $(a,z)$ using Mathematica and the regularized gamma function is shown to increase. So I guess that, as $(a,z) \rightarrow \infty$, since the function is bound between 0 and 1, that it saturates to 1. What do you think about that ?